# Taylor Series of f(x)=exp(x)

Tags: taylor-expansion

Regarding Taylor's Series theorem, 
i cannot prove this

> Determine the Taylor series $T_f$ of $f(x) = \exp{x}$ about an arbitrary $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and show that it is identical to $f(x)$
>   for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

i also may use the hint that  exp(x) = exp(a)*exp(x − a)

any ideas are appreciated !

Comment: Determining the Taylor series of $\operatorname{exp}(x)$ around zero is easy. Then use you formule to determine a Taylor series for $\operatorname{exp}(x-a)$. To do this, you need to rewrite that formula.

Comment: yes i know, i got : 
Σ from k=0 to +∞ of x^k/k! (k factorial) . 
next?

Comment: So given that you know the Taylor series for $f(x) = \exp{x}$, I think the next think that's required is an as-simple-as-possible expression for the Taylor series of $g(x) = \exp{(x-a)}$, using the given hint.

Comment: How do you define exponential function? Can you use $(\exp x)' = \exp x$?

Comment: f(x)=e^x therefore f'(x)=e^x .

Answer (score 0):

I guess by its very definition of Taylor expansion you have
$$ T_f(x)=e^a+\frac{e^a}{1}(x-a)+\frac{e^a}{2}(x-a)^2+\dots, $$
or more precisely 
$$T_f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^a}{k!}(x-a)^k=e^a \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(x-a)^k}{k!}=e^ae^{x-a}=e^x,$$
where I used the Definition of $\exp$. Maybe its formally better to write $exp(a)$ instead of $e^a$, depending on your definition.

Comment: "the Definition" is very poor wording when it comes to exponential function, as there is three standard ways to define it.

Comment: sure, but when it comes to taylor I guess that they will at least have a definition including series